# Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto create/update skip View

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, view, hbm2ddl

I have a mapped entity to a database view e.g.

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "my_view")
public class MyView {
 // some properties and getters
}
```

and my sql pendant is like `create view my_view as select * from thisAndThat and stupid logic;`

In my production environment it works like a charme.
Now in my integration tests I use Hibernate property  `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` = `update` to create my database setup with DbUnit in HSQL on the fly. Because I did not mark the entity table as view directly hibernate tries to create the database.

I am able to fix this by using flyway and add an migration script

```
drop table if exists my_view;
create view my_view AS ....;
```

First at all: It works

BUT: While building my project I get a lot of exceptions

```
2019-11-29 14:03:43,023  WARN  ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl:handleException:27 GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table my_view add constraint FKj50dxtl46l99jfi90uf4df7vo foreign key (other_table_id) references fonds" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table my_view add constraint FKj50dxtl46l99jfi90uf4df7vo foreign key (other_table_id) references other_table" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:433)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:615)
....
```

which is a) a bit disturbing and b) makes me nervous this could break in (near) future.

Do you know how I can skip creating a specific table dispite using `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Were you able to get this working? If so, how did you set up the dbUnit dataset to supply data for the view? I tried just including it like a normal table and end up with org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchTableException errors.

Comment: As accepted answer suggested I use annotation  \@Subselect("Select * from my_view"). That's the trick. FYI, I also use annotations \@Entity and \@Immutable

Comment: I do the same thing. If you look at the database logs, is hibernate creating a 'my_view' table during the deployment process? If you clear out the .script that hibernate creates, does it make any difference?  One of the issue I ran into was that the script originally included a create query for the table from before I changed it to a view so everything 'seemed' to be working. Once I deleted the script though, the view was no longer being added so dbunit could not find the table to populate.

Comment: hibernate isn't creating any table/view automatically. I added a init-script and create the view manually between compile and test-execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I would use @Subselect instead of @Table (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Subselect.html)

As for documentation @Subselect

> Map an immutable and read-only entity to a given SQL select
>   expression.